# Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Want to build a plug-in for Eclipse that provides custom features, as required by our project and is able to persist the data (provide client server capabilities).  Please suggest options.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a this http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html 
and this
http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a tad old but should still work : http://sourceforge.net/projects/jalcedo2

'JALCEDO is Rich Client Java Application develpment environment with database management tool accessible to create and modify database from client PC via http network based on Eclipse RCP. It support multiple database, including PostgreSQL and MySQL.'

Note that some of the code of this framework is now part of Eclipse DTP